# Ubuntu 14.04 | Use docker to isolate an untrusted C++ program

Tags: ubuntu, docker

As the title says, i need to run an untrusted C++ program into my prod server. I am trying with docker, but there are some things which are really unclear to me:

- i have created my own image starting from the ubuntu:14.04 image of Docker Hub.
- i have ran the container, installed build-essential, autoconf and dependencies
- then i quitted from the container, and committed changes building a new image starting from the ubuntu:14.04 one
- then i ran: `docker run -d <MY IMAGE ID> /root/myprogram &` and it seems to work properly

but i have a doubt: since the untrusted c++ program i have to run make use of a database, and since it updates db values every 10 minutes... do i have to commit changes to the image every 10 minutes, to avoid potential data loss?

if this is the case, i have to switch to another virtualization enviroment.....

Also, i am trying to manage a non root user **insider** the container, anyone has tried this before and has comments/suggestions about it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to run things as "root" inside of the Docker container, although you can (in theory) safely do so if you like to.

Normally when you want to have persistent data saved, what you want is a Docker volume which allows you to "mount" a folder from your host filesystem "inside" of the Docker container. Like the folder to which your database writes files. This is fairly safe in terms of untrusted code provided you pick a safe folder on the host and treat it as "dangerous" (obviously don't run files that appear in it on the host, they are untrusted).

Here's how to [use a volume](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/):

```
docker run -d myimagename -v /var/lib/myimages/untrusted/data/storage/on/host/:/path/in/container/for/db/ container-command
```

Technically in Linux, Docker is not virtualisation in the way you might be thinking -- it's not a VM. It's more like a FreeBSD jail (chroot and process isolation).

Comment: thank you for the right input, i have successfully set up the environment starting from your input.